# Trying to Execute a PHP File Which Contains PHP Includes - From the Command Line

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a PHP file (my-sites-notifier.php) in a WordPress Multisite installation... The PHP file utilizes the WordPress classes (by including /wp-admin/admin.php) in the file. The main script queries the database for (how many posts are in a queue) and sends an email notification if the number of posts in the queue drops below a threshold amount.

So, everything works great if I load the page in a browser, however, I need to set up a cronjob that calls the script. I created a sh file to call the PHP file for this purpose, containing the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
php -d display_errors=on my-sites-notifier-laucnh.php;
```

So the sh file works executing a simple PHP file with tasks like echo, however, when trying to execute (my-sites-notifier.php), which are dependent on the admin.php include (which itself calls other PHP includes), it doesn't work (and it is kicking back no errors).

Note, (my-sites-notifier.php) is using WordPress commands which make this doable for my low level of expertise. Attempting to build a native PHP file without using the WordPress classes/includes is beyond my skill level. Note, I have placed the sh file in the /wp-admin directory which sits in the same location as the PHP file I wish to execute.

So, the question is 'How do I Execute a PHP File Which Contains PHP Includes - From the Command Line?" If I can get this, all will be good

Comment: Depending on how file are included you may not be able to, the command line may not have access to certain server variables depending on your setup and may need absolute paths to these files. That said, have you googled to see if there is anything out there that does what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hey - yes, googled for hours.

Comment: OK - argh! I am realizing now that this a permissions issue. The WP commands I am using require Admin permissions.  Is there a way to mimic an admin login/session from the command line in order to execute a php page?

Comment: if you're using cron, add it to the correct user's cron file